# Can I have a 200 amp meter socket and 200 amp main shut with a 100 amp service? I can't upgrade to a 200 amp service cause I don't own the cabin

Tags: electrical

I need to know if it is safe or I will have to change it without a doubt.do I need to to call my cabin place and have them upgrade it?

Comment: If the main breaker is a 100 amps, everything should be okay.  If a 200 amp breaker on a 100 amp service, I would be talking to the power company to see if their wires to the cabin are 200 amp wires.

Comment: Since this is a US rental, you are not allowed to do any electrical work beyond changing light bulbs. Therefore the answer is "call your cabin place".

Comment: @FreeMan   It seems the OP is asking if it is safe, more than changing it themselves.

Comment: A picture of the panel might help.

Comment: Fair enough, but that's not particularly clear. There's not much about this question that's explicit or clear other than "rental = must call landlord to hire licensed electrician" to do work.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide clarity. As noted so far in these comments, we're not really sure what you're asking. Pretend we have no idea what equipment you've got and what it is that you're looking to find out. Explain it to us as though we're  5-year-olds to make sure we have a complete picture, then we can help you out.

Comment: If repairs are required you will need to check your Lease and State laws to determine who is responsible and who is allowed to do the work. Not all States prohibit lease holders from performing electrical work, but most residential lease agreements do.

Answer (score 1):

**The following answer applies to the same situation (200A vs. 100A) ONLY if you are allowed to the work.** In most places, a tenant normally can **NOT** do any electrical work, and usually the landlord can't either. The work must be done by a licensed electrician - this protects the tenant, the landlord and (if it is a multi-family building) other tenants. But the question is, in general, a valid one about sizing of different parts of electric service.

##### TL;DR Done properly (licensed electrician required if this is a rental), 200A "everything" is OK *except* that the main breaker must match the 100A service.

There are a few different places where current limits apply in a typical residential installation:

- Meter - Typically this will be rated for 200A even if everything else has not been upgraded to 200A. Why? Because at some point most utilities upgraded meters to a standardized 200A smart meter. If a particular home was originally built for 100A (or even smaller!) service, if the meter socket was standard then the utility could still install a 200A meter. (Note that some newer and/or larger homes have 400A/320A service, but 200A is the typical minimum for modern single-family homes.)
- Meter Socket - This is generally not replaced except if damaged (rare) or as part of a heavy-up. If the building originally had and still has 100A service then depending on age this may be 100A rated or 200A rated.
- Disconnect/Shutoff - This is where it gets interesting. The latest code requires an outside disconnect/shutoff. That can be a simple switch, in which case as long as it is rated at least as large as the utility service it is fine. It can *also* be the **main breaker** for the building, with anything from a very small to very large breaker panel. But in most locations older buildings will *not* have a separate outside disconnect/shutoff and will instead have as short as practical cable/wires from the meter socket to the main panel for the building - typically anywhere from 2 feet (if outside) to 10 feet (if inside).
- Utility Feed Wires ("service drop") - This is the cable/wire from the overhead pole or underground vault to the meter. Typically this will be sized based on the original service of the house and replaced only if there is a heavy-up or serious damage. However, there are exceptions. In my neighborhood every single utility wire (between poles on the street and the drop to each house) was replaced several years ago after several years of frequent weather-related outages. I am 99.99% certain that at that point my service drop was switched from the old, likely 100A, wires to new 200A wires. But the utility still went ahead and replaced the wires when I did my heavy-up a few years later - easier for the utility to have a standard practice than to actually think about the differences between installations.
- Wires from Meter (or Disconnect/Shutoff if there is one) to Main Breaker. This will generally be sized for the original service and, because builders are cheap, not oversized the way the service drop might be (because utilities tend to be big lazy "let's do it all the same" and builders tend to be "how can we save money"). This is the piece that I suspect is most likely to have a 100A limit.
- Main Breaker - This is the key. The main breaker protects the wires from the meter, and possibly the service drop, meter socket and meter. The wires from the meter are likely the weakest point (lowest current rating). The good news is that you (or in a rental, a licensed electrician) can install a much larger panel (e.g., 200A bus) as long as the main breaker is the correct size. That can be done by installing a panel with a 200A main breaker and swapping the main breaker for a smaller one or by installing a panel that comes with a 100A main breaker. It makes sense to install a panel with a 200A *bus rating* so that if you ever do get a service upgrade you can replace the main breaker with a 200A breaker.

Comment: Nice to see an answer that states ''a tenant normally can NOT", the State I live in allows commercial and residential lease holders to get permits. Was told the thinking is they would rather see work get inspected. Still my leases on my rentals prohibit my tenants from doing electrical.